# UI stuck during update of ProgressBar

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using Pcapdot.net DLLs in order to send buffer of packets to my network adapter. I  checked my Wireshark file and collected all the information e.g number of packets, duration etc..
My main class sends the buffer and has several properties (number of packets, duration..) In the main thread I am checking this class with BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged:

```
            bgWoSingle = new BackgroundWorker();
            bgWoSingle.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
bgWoSingle.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgW_ProgressChanged);
```

Every packet inside Wireshark file has a timstamp and of course I can send this buffer in other speed rate by increasing or decreasing the timestamp between the packets.
now my problem is:

One of the properties I am checking is how many packets I have already sent.  Because I know how many packets my file contains, I can show the progress via progress bar. If I am changing the send rate to maximum by deleting all the delay between the packets play, the speed is so fast and the progress bar and all the UI stuck until it's finished sending all the packets. How can I change it? Maybe update my ProgressBar via another thread?

this is my function who check my class:

```
  void bgW_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    //bla bla bla (check all Class properties)

        pcap = e.UserState as Pcap;
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; //here is my progressBar update


    //bla bla bla (check all Class properties)
  }
```

Comment: Does "stuck" mean unresponsive (ie. the window becomes gray on click, hence you MUST perform I/O from another thread) or just doesn't the progress bar update?

Comment: Yes it's become gray on click with "not responding" message until it's finish, how can i update all my bgW_ProgressChanged via another thread ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know Pcapdot.net, but I know Winforms so I can give you a couple of hints.

It appears that your UI is *stuck* in the sense that the window is unresponsive (you cannot click active buttons or edit textboxes, and if you try the window becomes gray). In that case you do have a threading problem. I don't know if that `BackgroundWorker` is a library class or one that you made, but you **must** be sure that any I/O operation is done in another thread. While the name suggests that it happens, I'm not sure about how you start the process against what is supposed by the API. For example, certain libraries allow you to call a `start` method that forks another thread, while others require you to call an `execute` method from a thread you already forked. This makes the difference.

In order to update your UI from a non-UI thread you must always use `[Control.Invoke][1]` method (if you need to pause your thread until UI gets updated) or `Control.BeginInvoke` (if you want to proceed ASAP).

My `Lambda-fu` is not trained daily, so please correct me if I make an error in my syntax

```
progressBar1.Invoke(delegate() {progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;});
```

<strike>In the second case in which your UI is *stuck* in the sense that the progress bar won't progress, first make sure that the event is fired. Second and most important, you **cannot** update UI from a non-UI thread. Imperative!</strike>

If you run that `progressChanged` method inside a try-catch I see troubles, because when you update the progressBar percentage you get an exception that could be masked. I also hope that `ProcessPercentage` is an integer between 0 and 100 and not a `double` between 0 and 1, something that causes the bar not to apparently progress.

Comment: I just read your comment please ignore the second part of my question

Comment: sorry for asking but i did not understand what i should do, what is the best way to update my UI ?

Comment: Calling Invoke method with a lambda. Example in a few seconds

Comment: this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { }); ?

Comment: Well my code is not the best example of a "lambda expression". Better call it with its real name: *anonymous delegate*

Comment: Control.Invoke is not necessary as BackgroundWorker takes care of invoking on the UI thread for you.

Comment: is it recommended to put all bgW_ProgressChanged function inside  this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { }); ? (this function only check my class properties and update my UI)

Comment: @falukky no, it's unrecommended at all

Comment: As a general rule, you should call Control.Invoke only for executing instructions that concretely updates the UI, or at most performs basic instructions like cheap maths (ie converting double to int percentile). I don't know what more you do in your event handler. However as @slugart told us, in this case (and only if you use BackgroundWorker) you are exempt from calling Control.Invoke

Answer (score 8):

You are simply calling ReportProgress() too often.  So often that the UI thread is flooded with invoke requests and doesn't get around to its regular duties anymore.  Like painting and responding to input events.  Because when it is ready to execute the next notification, there'll be yet another request to call the ProgressChanged event handler, it goes first.

You'll need to slow it down to a reasonable rate.  Reasonable is easy to define, you are doing this for human eyes only.  Which cannot see anything but a blur when you do this faster than 20 times per second.  You are way past that right now, probably beyond a thousand times per second.  One simple way is to just count off 50 records before you call ReportProgress.  Tweak as necessary.