# reportProgress in backgroundWorker not work until operation completed

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

When I call worker.ReportProgress() in the `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` Event, it won't work and the `ProgressChanged` event is only raised at the end of the `for` loop.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string writePath = Path.Combine(bookPath, "bytes");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = Form1.book.Select("select * from book");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(writePath);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        int pagenumber = Convert.ToInt32(dr["pageNumber"]);
        string text = dr["text"].toString();
        byte[] codes = tocode.convertTobyte(text.ToCharArray());

        File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(writePath, pagenumber.ToString()),codes);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((pagenumber * 100) / dt.Rows.Count);
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
     progressBarMain.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Comment: Is your BackgroundWorker's `WorkerReportsProgress` property set to true?  And is the event handler set up properly?  Also, note that the ReportProgress call just raises the event and returns immediately, so if the worker finishes its task quickly you may not see the event code firing before the worker finishes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UI stuck during update of ProgressBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9861760/ui-stuck-during-update-of-progressbar)

Comment: Hi and thanks, Yes WorkerReportProgress property setted as true.all operations in doWork Event work completely and after finishing the loop progressBar value will change from 0 to 100.

Comment: Can you please provide the declaration of your `BackgroundWorker` and how it is started?